# local variable initialization were wrong java

Tags: java

I am new to java, why a, b,c initialization are wrong in the following code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length < 2) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("we need 2 argumeents");
    else { 
       int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
       int b = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
       int c = a+b;
    }
        System.out.println(a + " + " + b + " = " + c);
}
```

Comment: define "wrong"?

Comment: Because they go out of scope at the end of the `else` block you can't print them after that. You throw an `Exception` in the `if` block. You don't need an `else`.

Comment: Thank you Elliott Frisch, I got it , my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java works differently compared to JavaScript. Every {} block has an own variable scope. Variables defined inside a block are not visible outside.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  {
    int x=1;
    System.out.println(x); // prints 1
  }
  {
    int x=2;
    System.out.println(x); // prints 2
  }
  // System.out.println(x); // error: cannot find symbol
}
```